# Google Cloud TTS Voice selection

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-text-to-speech

I just started to use the Google's TTS api, when I list the available voices api lists the names of the voices as

- tr-TR-Standart-A
- tr-TR-Standart-B
- ...

What should I write to the code below to select for example Standart-B voice?

texttospeech.types.VoiceSelectionParams(language_code='tr-TR')

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you tell us a bit more about which platform you're using, ideally with sample code of how you're calling the API at the moment? That would make it easier to give a concrete example.

Comment: Having said that, I can write a C# example and then hopefully you can take that...

Comment: Oh sorry, I'm using python.

Comment: Right - I've added a snippet at the end of my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example in C# - you need to specify both the language code *and* the name in the `VoiceSelectionParams`:

```
using Google.Cloud.TextToSpeech.V1;
using System;
using System.IO;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var client = TextToSpeechClient.Create();

        // List the voices, just for reference
        foreach (var voice in client.ListVoices("tr-TR").Voices)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(voice.Name);
        }

        // Synthesize some speech
        var input = new SynthesisInput { Text = "This is a demo of Google Cloud text to speech" };
        // The language code is always required, even when it's sort of part of the name
        var voiceSelection = new VoiceSelectionParams
        {
            LanguageCode = "tr-TR",
            Name = "tr-TR-Standard-B"
        };
        var audioConfig = new AudioConfig { AudioEncoding = AudioEncoding.Mp3 };
        var response = client.SynthesizeSpeech(input, voiceSelection, audioConfig);
        File.WriteAllBytes("test.mp3", response.AudioContent.ToByteArray());
    }
}
```

Judging by the documentation, I *think* in Python you'd want:

```
voice = texttospeech.types.VoiceSelectionParams(
    language_code='tr-TR',
    name='tr-TR-Standard-B')
```

Comment: @TugrulAgrikliStudent: Could you give a bit more detail than that? I assume you're getting an error of some description - what's that error? I can't help you without more information. (The C# code definitely *does* work.)